# Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I created a new React JS app using the Visual Studio 2022 Project Template "Standalone JavaScript React Template"

When I run the project I see the react logo just like when you use "create-react-app" (I'm assuming that Visual Studio 2022 creates the project in the same way)

I want to use Bootstrap in my project so I installed the module by going to the root directory of the project and typing "npm install bootstrap" I can see that the module is installed in the package.json

When I try and import bootstrap in my index.js using this line:

```
import "/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

Then run the app I get this error:

```
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
    You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/
```

My question is what is the correct way to import and use bootstrap in my project, did I install it in the right way or is there a diffrent method?

This is my full index.js file for clarity:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import "/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();
```

UPDATE: See sctructure of project
[image]

Comment: Try `import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`. You need to give the relative path from the **src** folder.

Comment: @tromgy thanks but that just resulted in this error:

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'' in 'C:\Projects\RockLife\RockLife.ReactFrontEnd\src'

Comment: That's strange, because I followed the same sequence with VS 2022 and it imported it without problems. What is the full path to **node_modules** in your project?

Comment: @tromgy really...? I have updated the question with a screen shot so you can see the structure.... I think there is more too it.... you can't seem to have the module outside the SRC folder..

Comment: Remove the `/` prefix... `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`. With the `/`, the bundler thinks it's a filesystem path

Comment: I now think what @Phil suggested is the best. I actually tried that at first, and it wasn't working, so I tried that relative path... Now, however it also works for me. Actually have tried 3 ways now: Windows with VS 2022 project, Windows with CRA project and on macOS with CRA. Don't know if it was some caching issue. In any case it looks neater.

Comment: @Phil removing the / worked thanks! - if you add an answer I will mark it as correct.